# Add delete raw button to table from database Django

Tags: python, html, django, database

I have a form on the page that adds data to the database and displays it in a table

I need to add a button that will delete a specific row by id from the database

index.html

```
<tbody>
                            {% for expense_item in expense_items %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ expense_item.username}}</td>
                                <td>{{ expense_item.expense_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ expense_item.category }}</td>
                                <td>{{ expense_item.cost }}zł</td>
                                <td>{{ expense_item.date_added}}</td>
                                <td>BUTTON HERE</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
```

Models.py

```
class ExpenseInfo(models.Model):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='NoName')
     expense_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     cost = models.FloatField()
     budget_id = models.CharField(default='0123456789', max_length=10)
     date_added = models.DateField()
     user_expense = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Views.py

```
def add_item(request):
budget_id = request.user.last_name
name = request.POST['expense_name']
category = request.POST['category']
expense_cost = request.POST['cost']
expense_date = request.POST['expense_date']
try:
    ExpenseInfo.objects.create(username=request.user, expense_name=name, category=category, cost=expense_cost,
                               date_added=expense_date, user_expense=budget_id)
except ValueError or TypeError:
    print('No data.')
return HttpResponseRedirect('app')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a button inside `form` tag, and the `form` tag is inside `td` tag like this:

```
<tbody>
   {% for expense_item in expense_items %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{ expense_item.username}}</td>
      <td>{{ expense_item.expense_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ expense_item.category }}</td>
      <td>{{ expense_item.cost }}zł</td>
      <td>{{ expense_item.date_added}}</td>
      <td>
         <form method="POST" action={% some url%}>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit">Button Here</button>
         </form>
      </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: I know how to add a button, but I am asking for a function that will be attached to the button